# incomprehensibility with span tag and css "margin-*" properties

Tags: html, css

span tag dont support css `margin-top` property.

Q: Why?

A: because span is not block element ?!

Ok, but why support span tag `margin-left` property ?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/h4xNK/

Comment: CSS specifications define which properties apply in each case. The “why” question calls for opinions, speculations, and debate, so it’s not constructive.

Answer (score 4):

As explained by @flem This is because the `span` element is an inline element, not a block level element, unlike `div` which is. If you want it to behave differently you need to explicitly state this through `display:inline-block` or `block`.

If you can control the markup  then depending on its context and content you may want to consider actually using a `div`.

Comment: inline-block doesn't have great support in older browser versions.

Comment: I know this, hence me saying `or` which gives you the option to change this for those browsers. The problem with `block` in those older browsers is that it pushes out the other content, you would then need to `float:left` the element so that it mimicked the `inline` behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

HTML (inline) flows across the page (hence supporting `margin-left`). You can almost *mimic* `margin-top` with `line-height`, `padding`, and `baseline-shift`.

Comment: padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, but only left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content. padding and margin operate in the same way on inline elements.

Comment: or better yet display:block and then it behaves like a div

Comment: @user1721135 Or actually use a 1div1...

Answer (score 1):

Elements with display `inline` are ignoring properties like margin-top; and `span` has display set to inline by default, but you can change it to `block` or `inline-block` and then it'll work - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4xNK/)

Comment: `inline-block` doesn't have great support in older browser versions. If OP wanted it to behave as a `block`, OP would surely use a `block` element e.g. `div`.

Comment: @flem Older browsers? Do you mean crappy IE?

Comment: IE for one. And just because it's "crappy" doesn't mean nobody uses it. It still needs to be supported in many cases.

Comment: @flem In many cases you also need to write a separate css for IE, anyway.